# Detect runner type in postman/newman pre-request script

Tags: postman, newman, postman-pre-request-script

**Question:**

How do I detect that newman is running the requests instead of postman in the prerequest?

**Context:**

I'm using the new postman feature `pm.execution.skipRequest()` to skip requests in the prerequest script (see [this](https://blog.postman.com/optimize-your-api-testing-workflow-with-postmans-skip-request-feature/) if you're interested). Within postman this works great, but it's not implemented within newman yet. I'm using newman as collection runner, which will then throw an error and cancel the iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Use an environment variable and set the default to "Collection".  When you send the request using Newman, use the command line option to overwrite that environment variable with the string "Newman" which you can then use to detect where the request is running from.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#newman-run-collection-file-source-options

```
--env-var "<environment-variable-name>=<environment-variable-value>"
```

Comment: I hoped to do this automatically without having to add external environment variables, but if that's impossible, this is a good workaround, Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully the feature will be added properly to Newman at some point in the very near future.